# Why has a (C-)stack a maximum of 2mb?

Tags: linux, memory, stack-overflow, allocation

This question is about stack overflows, so where better to ask it than here.

If we consider how memory is used for a program (a.out) in unix, it is something like this:

```
| etext | stack, 2mb | heap ->>>
```

And I have wondered for a few years now why there is a restriction of 2MB for the stack. Consider that we have 64 bits for a memory address, then why not allocate like this:

```
| MIN_ADDR                                                              MAX_ADDR|
| heap ->>>>                                                 <<<- stack | etext |
```

MAX_ADDR will be somewhere near 2^64 and MIN_ADDR somewhere near 2^0, so there are many bytes in between which the program can use, but are not necessarily accounted for by the kernel (by actually assigning pages for them). The heap and stack will probably never reach each other, and hence the 2MB limit is not needed ( and would instead have a ~1.8446744e+19 bytes limit). If we are scared that they will reach each other, then set the limit to 2^63 or some bizarre and enormous number.

Furthermore, the heap grows from low to high, so our kernel can still resize blocks of memory (allocated with for example malloc) without necessarily needing to shift the content.

Moreover, a stack frame is always static in size in some way. So we never need to resize there, if we do, that would be awkward anyway, since we also need to change the whole pointer structure used by *return* and created by *call*.

I read this as an answer on another stackoverflow question:

"My intuition is the following. The stack is not as easy to manage as the heap. The stack need to be stored in continuous memory locations. This means that you cannot randomly allocate the stack as needed, but you need to at least reserve virtual addresses for that purpose. The larger the size of the reserved virtual address space, the fewer threads you can create."

Source: [Why is the page size of Linux (x86) 4 KB, how is that calcualted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543748/why-is-the-page-size-of-linux-x86-4-kb-how-is-that-calcualted)

But we have loads of memory addresses! So this makes no sense. So why 2MB?

The reason I ask is that allocating memory on the stack is quite safe with respect to dangling pointers and memory leaks:

e.g. I prefer

```
int foo[5];
```

instead of

```
int *foo = malloc(5*sizeof(int));
```

Since it will deallocate by itself. Also, allocation on the stack is faster than allocation executed by malloc. However, If I allocate an image (i.e. a jpeg or png) on the stack, I am in a dangerous zone of overflowing the stack.

Another point on this matter, why not also allow this:

```
int *huge_list_of_data = malloc(1000*sizeof(char), 10 000 000 000*sizeof(char))
```

where we allocate a list object, which has initially the size of 1KB, but we ask the kernel to allocate it such that the page it is put on is not used for anything else, and that we want to have 10GB of pages behind it, which can be (partially) swapped in when necessary.

This way we don't need 10GB of memory, we only need 10GB of memory *addresses*.

So why no:

```
void *malloc( unsigned long, unsigned long );
```

?

In essence: WHY NOT USE THE PAGING SYSTEM OF UNIX TO SOLVE OUR MEMORY ALLOCATION PROBLEMS?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: It is actually much more complex today. Run `cat /proc/self/maps` to understand the memory address of the process running that `cat` command.

Comment: You can use `mmap`. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16088155/841108)

Comment: Thank you for all your comments! I will review them and get back to this.

Comment: My current understanding is that the limit is there to prevent problems when a process creates many threads, since then each thread needs to have a piece of (virtual) address space for its stack.