# Are Logical records sizes determined in such a way as to match existing physical record size? Why/why not?

Tags: file, operating-system, filesystems

As I dive deeper into understanding files and file systems, this question came to mind and I was curious to find some sort of answer but have yet to find any.

Comment: Are you referring to the difference between cache lines, pages, and disk blocks?

Comment: yes that's what I am referring to @wxz

Comment: Pages can be variable sizes, although typically 4KB, you can have huge pages and it's a tradeoff between space and metadata overhead. You can read a more lengthy discussion on page sizes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543748/why-is-the-page-size-of-linux-x86-4-kb-how-is-that-calculated). So page size doesn't necessarily match physical record size, which I think historically have been 512 byte disk sectors.